# How to connect to an inside directory in the main GitHub repository?

Tags: github, heroku, repository, heroku-connect

I could connect to a main github repository like https://github.com/XXXXX/XXXX-XXXX/ with my Heroku Connect to GitHub. How to connect to inside its github repository directory tree like https://github.com/XXXXX/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/tree/main/XXXX-XXXX?

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions as such

Just clone the repo, and then `cd` to the inside directory, after performing any change, commit the code, push the code. No other directories will be effected.

Comment: Hello, But I can't cd to the inside directory from my heroku app since it automatically deploy branch to the main directory only. Can you show me a screenshot about how to cd to the inside directory from my heroku app when I click connect to github from my heroku app? Thank you.